# Automatically delete child entity using orphanRemoval Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Currently I have the following 2 entities with a one to many relationship -

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_line")
@IdClass(InvoiceLinePK.class)
public class InvoiceLineEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "line_id")
  private String lineId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "client_id")
  private Integer clientId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "invoice_id")
  private String invoiceId;

  @Column(name = "item_id")
  private String itemId;

  @Column(name = "amount")
  private BigDecimal amount;

  @ManyToOne
  private InvoiceEntity invoice;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
@IdClass(InvoicePK.class)
@Data
public class InvoiceEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "client_id")
  private Integer clientId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "invoice_id")
  private String invoiceId;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;

  @Column(name = "txn_total_amount")
  private BigDecimal txnTotalAmount;

  @Column(name = "created_time", updatable = false)
  @CreationTimestamp
  private Date createdTime;

  @Column(name = "updated_time")
  @UpdateTimestamp
  private Date updatedTime;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "invoice")
  private List<InvoiceLineEntity> invoiceLines;

}
```

In a case wherein let's say, one of my existing invoice has 3 lines and I receive a request that this particular invoice has been updated and it now has only 1 line instead of the previous 3 (so the other 2 have to be deleted), I would like to create a new Invoice object with this 1 InvoiceLineEntity and then do a `invoiceRepository.save(invoice)`

I am expecting that the other 2 InvoiceLine records would be automatically deleted because the `orphanRemoval` flag is enabled.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this relationship by tweaking the entity relationship structure of the above 2 entities?

Answer (score 0):

Your child entity must be the owner of the relationship, so that the orphans are allowed to be deleted

If you change and add `mappedBy` to that relation

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "bill")
  private List<BillLine> billLines;
```

Then the BillLine must also hold a reference

```
public class BillLine {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "line_id")
  private String lineId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "company_id")
  private Integer companyId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "bill_id")
  private String billId;

  @Column(name = "item_id")
  private String itemId;

  @Column(name = "amount")
  private BigDecimal amount;

  @ManyToOne
  private Bill bill;

}
```

Now it will remove the orphans

Also since you have multiple `@Id` on each entity. Do you know that you have to either declare a composite class or an embeddable class? Without one of those the multiple Ids are not valid.

Edit:

**1)** My bad mappedBy should be placed inside `@OneToMany` and not `@JoinColumn`. I have corrected it in my answer

**2)** Remove `@JoinColumn`. It is wrong in your configuration. By default `@OneToMany` inserts a column in the side of the `@ManyToOne` which holds the references to the primary table. You can override those default configurations and create a separate table for mappings but then you need the `@JoinTable` and I don't see any reason for that here.

This here

```
 @JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "company_id"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "bill_id", referencedColumnName = "bill_id") })
```

definitely does not belong on `@OneToMany`

The following can be applied to `@OneToMany` but as said before I don't see any reason to do that and complicate a simple mapping which does not require a separate table.

```
@JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "company_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bill_id", referencedColumnName = "bill_id") )
```

Check here for more information [Jpa primary key](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id)

Comment: *Without one of those the multiple Ids are not valid.* - No, this is valid. But this is hibernate specific , see [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-associations)

Comment: you mean that this is valid for spring Jpa?

Comment: if hibernate is used as jpa provider, yes, this is possible mapping for composite identifiers

Comment: yeah you have right. However as stated in documentation `The restriction that a composite identifier has to be represented by a "primary key class" (e.g. @EmbeddedId or @IdClass) is only JPA-specific.` So they are going out of lines of JPA specifications for some features.

Comment: @Boug Yeah I have a separate composite ID class for both of these entities. ```mappedBy``` is a parameter inside @OneToMany and not @Column clause Also, I am not able to even run the code by using the mappedBy parameter. It gives me the following error - ```Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn: com.db.example.dbexample.entities.Bill.billLines```

Comment: @VinayNikhil I have edited my answer. Check the reason of failing now

Comment: @Boug Still seeing an exception - ```Unknown column 'billlin0_.bill_company_id' in 'field list'```

Comment: @Boug basically while generating the bill_line query it is referencing to the bill_id and company_id columns as bill_bill_id and bill_company_id. Observe the extra ```bill``` before the column names

Comment: select billlin0_.company_id as company_i1_3_0_, billlin0_.bill_id as bill_2_3_0_, billlin0_.line_id as line_id3_3_0_, billlin0_.amount as amount4_3_0_, billlin0_.bill_company_id as bill_6_3_0_, billlin0_.bill_bill_id as bill_7_3_0_, billlin0_.item_id as item_id5_3_0_, billent1_.company_id as company_i1_2_1_, billent1_.bill_id as bill_2_2_1_, billent1_.created_time as created_3_2_1_, billent1_.description as descript4_2_1_, billent1_.txn_total_amount as txn_tota5_2_1_, billent1_.updated_time as updated_6_2_1_

Comment: please update your question and post the complete code of your entities with annotations and composite classes and also the error stacktrace. Something is malformed with your entities. If you show the complete information we can correct it

Comment: @Boug I have updated my entity names but the structure is more or less the same. I have posted a generic design question instead of the error that I am seeing and I am open to any suggestions/modifications to my structure in order to solve my use case

Comment: post also the stack trace from the error that you receive